# Subquery with conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a query where the joined column is 0 for the input, it should use a different condition for the where.

Original query

```
Select * from dbo.Q
WHERE TX IN (SELECT TX FROM DBO.SM WHERE SITE_ID in (SELECT PSITE_ID FROM SITES WHERE SITE_NUMBER = @site_number)
```

If Psite_id is 0 or NULL though, I want the subquery to use ASite_id in the subquery instead of Psite_id. I tried using case but then it gave me errors as below:

```
Select * from dbo.Q
WHERE TX IN (SELECT TX FROM DBO.SM WHERE SM.SITE_ID in (case when (SELECT PSITE_ID FROM SITES WHERE SITE_NUMBER = @site_number)=0 then SELECT ASITE_ID FROM SITES WHERE SITE_NUMBER = @site_number ))
```

I could do a join but I'm still not quite sure how to address this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a Case must include the following parts:

```
Case When <condition> Then <value> else <value> End
```

So, if I understand your need well, then it should work:

```
Select * 
From dbo.Q 
Where TX IN (Select TX 
             From DBO.SM 
             Where SITE_ID IN 
                        (Select Case When IsNull(PSITE_ID, 0) = 0 
                                     Then ASITE_ID Else PSITE_ID End
                         From SITES 
                         Where SITE_NUMBER = @site_number))
```

Depending on the kind of SQL server you are using (which you do not specify), the IsNull() function might not exist. For example in Oracle instead of IsNull() you must use NVL().